# Importing values from a SharePoint Calendar to Excel form

Tags: excel, sharepoint-calendar

My company runs EMS Service for private parties, sports events etc. We are scheduling our tasks with a SharePoint calendar. For each event one has to create a Excel sheet containing time, date, task number, names etc. For busy weekends we have to create about 100 Excel sheets per day . The data is already written in the SharePoint Calendar. Is their a way to access the SharePoint Calendar with a VBA macro and automatically get the desired data in the Excel spreadsheet ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have added all the dates and tasks to your SharePoint Calendar, you can go to the Connect & Export settings and export all the information into on Excel spreadsheet. I use this method often! it has saved me hours of work.

hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

there are couple of ways to achieve this and already answered on technet

please refer

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/396fb71d-5fda-4fe1-9d39-4332944bead1/import-excel-data-into-sharepoint-calendar

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/ddc20756-a191-434e-866b-97523b405a82/import-excel-data-into-sharepoint-calendar

Comment: Please post some details also rather than just posting a link here, because once the link is broken its of no use for community members.